# How to save a field as 'null' to Firebase if no value is entered in TextFormField

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

'?? null' works if only the first field has it, however it won't save if the other field(s) also has '?? null'. Is there a better way to write this?

```
onPressed: () async {
              final uid =
                  await TheProvider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
              //save data to firebase
              widget.contact.name = oneController.text;
              widget.contact.phoneNumber = int.parse(twoController.text);
              widget.contact.location = threeController.text;
              widget.contact.rating = int.parse(fourController.text);
              widget.contact.instagram = fiveController.text;
              widget.contact.birthday = int.parse(sixController.text);
              widget.contact.notes = sevenController.text;
await db
                  .collection("userData")
                  .doc(uid)
                  .collection("Contacts")
                  .add(widget.contact.toJson());
```

The Map in the models file

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'Name': name,
    'PhoneNumber': phoneNumber,
    'Location': location,
    'Rating': rating,
    'Instagram': instagram,
    'Birthday': birthday,
    'Notes': notes,
  };
}
```

Comment: why not store an empty `string`. Something like, `'Name': widget.contact.name ?? " ",`

Comment: Hi, interesting, you could perhaps put all the values in a map, then create new map with only the non-null values, and insert that.

Comment: try using the operator earlier during the assigning itself like this: `widget.contact.name = oneController.text ?? null` `widget.contact.phoneNumber = int.parse(twoController.text) ?? null`

Comment: @Hamza same issue I'm afraid

Comment: @joyterence :( the problem persists

Comment: Could you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837496/8394595) and let us know if this works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integers are what are preventing the save. Instead of using int.parse, use int.tryParse.